# Keyframes aren't working correctly

Tags: rigging, bones, keyframes, dopesheet

I've just recently been having a problem where I set my character up, set the first keyframe at 0 but when I try to set other keyframes later on my character makes no movements. (I have all bones keyframed correctly and everything). Some parts make very minor movements but they aren't what I keyframed and they are instant too. Also I don't know if this makes a difference or not but I am using the dopesheet.

I`m unable to show more than 2 pictures so I got rid of the first one. Basically it showed my starting keyframes on frame 0 (I had everything keyframed just like in the second image). The character at frame 0 looks like how he does in the 3rd image.

Now in this image I have moved all the parts I needed to move, and keyframed every single part even if I didn`t move it. 
[image]

After I keyframed everything in the previous photo, I moved to a different keyframe and all the parts I moved snapped back to look more like the keyframes in frame 0 instead of what I had in frame 9. I honestly have no idea why this is happening and really need help figuring out why this is happening.
[image]

My .blend file can be found here: [image]

Comment: I guess this problem is so peculiar, that you should share your model (eg with http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for others to see whats wrong... or at least explain much more and add images...

Comment: @m.ardito I have added photos and explained what`s going on.

Comment: @Firesknight please provide a .blend file as m.ardito suggested to be able to help you

Comment: @m.ardito [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2669" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2669/)

Answer (score 2):

You have the action set as a one frame track in the NLA, so you are only getting one frame of animation from it.

You can either extend the length or remove the action from the NLA to see the entire animation.

[image: NLA settings]